# Consuming JSONP in Google Apps Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, jsonp

I'd like to consume the following URL in my Google Apps Script:
`http://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/emr/pricing-mapr.min.js`

Using the typical `response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()` doesn't really work, it just returns the JSON surrounded by `callback()`. Is there a way to consume JSONP with Google Apps Script?

Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  getEmrPricingData_();

}

/*
 * Get EMR Prices
 *
 */
function getEmrPricingData_() {
  var emr_url = "http://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/emr/pricing-mapr.min.js"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(emr_url).getContentText();
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the function callback() in your code, and eval() your JSONP response to execute that function.  For example to handle JSONP responses on a project of mine I created this function:

```
function callback(data){
    return data;
}
```

and in my request function:

```
var result = eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + uri, options).getContentText());
```

Comment: In case of security concerns would rather extract the data as a regex match rather than use eval. It depends on you view of how evil eval is.